# Using Swig to access C arrays in structs stored as pointer/size from C#

Tags: c#, c++, c, swig

I have a C struct in a C++ library like this:

```
struct StructA
{
   int Number;
   float FloatNumber;
}

struct StructB
{
   int NumStructA;
   StructA* StructAArray;
}
```

where StructAArray is a pointer to an array of StructA objects of size NumStructA.

I want to use swig to wrap this to C# so that I can access each element of StructAArray, but swig exposes it as a single instance of StructA in C#.

Is there a typemap I can use to expose StructB.StructAArray as an array in C#?

Comment: Did you try what the [documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/CSharp.html#CSharp_arrays) has to say on the subject?

Comment: Generally, when working on the interface between C# and native code (like C or C++), one uses P/Invoke

Comment: fredrik, That documentation is for converting from C# to C++. I am doing the opposite. Does the technique still apply?